# Cannot get page to redirect using PHP

Tags: php, forms, redirect

Everything on the form works but it will not redirect to another page. It continues to give a text message.  I've added a `header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/');` but no luck.  I'm new at PHP and would really appreciate help in fixing this code.

Current code:

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {        

   $email_to = "me@email.com";     
   $email_subject = "Contact Request";                 

   function died($error) {                
      echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";         
      echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";         
      echo $error."<br /><br />";         
      echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";         
      die();
   }

   if( !isset($_POST['full_name']) ||         
       !isset($_POST['agency']) ||   
       !isset($_POST['title']) ||         
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||       
       !isset($_POST['phone']) ||         
       !isset($_POST['comments'])) {         
     died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');            
   }       

   $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // required     
   $agency = $_POST['agency']; // required  
   $title = $_POST['title']; // required        
   $email = $_POST['email']; // required     
   $phone = $_POST['phone']; // not required     
   $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

   $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";           

   function clean_string($string) {       
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");       
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);     
   }           

   $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";     
   $email_message .= "Agency: ".clean_string($agency)."\n";     
   $email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($title)."\n";    
   $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";     
   $email_message .= "phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";     
   $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";             

   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
              'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
   @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);   
   header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/'); 
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it is actually `die()` not `died()`

Comment: @user3344801 Is there anything in the error log? What happens if you try just redirecting to another file? Also, be sure to put `exit();` right after any header redirect attempts, otherwise PHP will continue to run the script (this might be the issue, but it's needed either way)

Comment: Are you positive this breaks down on `header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/');` that line?

Answer (score 0):

Is the last line of code a typo in your question or part of your code?

```
<?php } ?>
```

If it's really part of your code, php is going to try and execute '}' and most likely screw up.
You don't say what the text message is that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ?> after this line

header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/');